# How to validate client in java rmi before executing actual service

Tags: java, rmi

I created a sample java RMI application, when client sends a request service on server creates some files in a drive.
 Here I'd like to authenticate the client before executing the actual service.
In general using RMI url we can call the service from any machine.
 Can anyone help on how to authenticate client before executing the service ?[image]

Comment: A slightly heavy-handed way would be for the client to cryptographically sign the set of files he/she uploads.  If the server knows the public key of authorized clients (or trusts a common CA from which they are created), it could verify the signature on the files before processing them, proving their origin.  Might be easier to authenticate the users *before* they upload though.  You might get better answers if you give a little more detail about the intended process (or end-user objective).

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b thanks for the suggestion.Instead of using SSL, I'd like to add user validation.